# Call a URL in Excel 2010 without opening the webpage

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My Excel sheet consists of mobile numbers.

I want to pass each number to a URL and perform a certain code on my server.

I have created a button and have wrote the below code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    strURL = "http://xxxxxxx.com/myAPI.php?mobilenumber=" _
    & ActiveCell.Value
    Call Sheets("Sheet1").Navigate(strURL)

    End Sub
```

But unfortunately it is not working.

Please not that I don't want to redirect to `http://xxxxxxx.com/myAPI.php` just calling it and pass the `mobilenumber` to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it using XMLHttp. Below is sample code.

**XMLHttpRequest** object is used to exchange data with a server behind the scenes

```
 Sub SendSms()

    Dim URL As String
    URL = "http://xxxxxxx.com/myAPI.php?mobilenumber=" & ActiveCell.Value

    Dim xml As Object
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml.Open "GET", URL, False
    xml.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: here i want to pass the active cell value(ie mobile number)

Comment: @arok what parameters are required it depends on your site `xxxxxxx.com` . If you provide me the link i can help you with that.

Comment: Please use this link to download my files filedropper.com/testing